# OpenID realm field for user authentication in packaged chrome app

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, android-pay, google-chrome-app

if I'm using Google OpenID to authenticate users for my packaged app I need to fill in OpenID realm field. The problem is that I have no clue what to enter. The documentation sais:

> In the text field that appears, enter the realm that your app will use
>   to query Google's OpenID service. This must be exactly the same as
>   the value of the openid.realm field in your authentication requests.

What exactly should I enter? where I can see/get this value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenID realm is mostly used when you are migrating from OpenID 2.0 protocol to OpenID Connect.

Basically if don't know what to specify there you may leave it blank, but in general this field value must correspond to `openid.realm` request parameter (optional) when building an authentication request to Google.

Please, read [Migrating from OpenID 2.0 to OpenID Connect](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenID2Migration) and [OpenID Connect](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect) documents from Google Identity Platform section for more details.

**P.S.** please, tag you OpenID related question with `google-oauth` label to get the response quickly ;)

Comment: in short words meaning `openid.realm` is used to be the root URI of your application e.g: [https://your-app.appspot.com/](https://your-app.appspot.com/) but since we are talking about packaged app you may leave it blank